# Angular 2 using template reference variable ngForm as input binding

Tags: angular

I'm building a component that has an input 'valid'. If I bind the value to a member of the parent component, things work well. But if I bind it to a template reference like so

```
<step [valid]="name.valid">

      <input type="text" name="name"
             #name="ngForm"
             [(ngModel)]="name"
             required>

</step>
```

I get

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'.
>   Current value: 'false'

which I partly understand. I get that the ngForm valid check occurs after component initialization, and therefore the value has changed.
What I don't get is why this is a problem, and why this can be solved by calling enableProdMode(), and why enableProdMode() is a bad idea.

I also tried 
ChangeDetectorRef with .detach() and .reattach() to temporary disable change detection, which didn't solve it and sounds like a bad idea too.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

That's a known issue. Use instead

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <step [valid]="f.controls['name'].valid">
```

Comment: Thanks. If I try that I get
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Comment: Some more details what can not be assigned to what?

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? How does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: I use 2.0.0-rc.1 and the form looks like <form #f="ngForm">.

I'm sorry, I think that error was unrelated.

Do I also need to keep the #name="ngForm" on the input element? If I do that I get

Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("

If I don't, I get

TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: No, you don't need `#name="ngForm"` but you need some way to make the input an Angular form control. Try adding `ngControl="name"` then `#name="ngForm"` shouldn't throw anymore (in case you need it for something else).